# iPhone app too big, don't want to use test flight, adhoc deployment

Tags: ios, heroku

I am working on iphone app that is about 600mb in size. I need to give it to beta testers but I've had bad experiences with test flight, I was thinking of doing this in the style of adhoc deployment were I produce an app.ipa file.

I have two questions here :

1 : Is this a good idea? Should I assume that testing an app that has been packaged for enterprise deployment is the same as if being submitted to the app store?

2 : Is there a way to put this on heroku, so I can direct testers for the link? or any other recommendations for a free solution are appreciated.

Thanks

Just to clarify, this app will eventually end up in the app store, the enterprise hack is just a way around test flight.

Answer (score 0):

In our company, we produce an enterpise IPA and upload it to an in-house SFTP server for our clients / testers to use.  I would recommend against putting it on a site without a login, because distributing an enterprise app openly is a violation of the terms of use for enterprise accounts.

That being said, there will be absolutely no difference in the binary of your file between an enterprise build and an app store build (unless you use custom build scripts for each that differ in some way).  The only difference is the provisioning profile and the code signature.

Heroku is a PaaS provider, and it would be way overkill to use it just for this purpose.

Comment: this app will eventually end up in the app store, the enterprise hack is just a way around test flight.

Comment: In the end, that's all ours was too.  The app is on the app store now.  I'm just saying, if you put it on a public server where anyone with a link can get it, then what is the difference between that and distributing it?  At least if you put a login on then you can claim that you were distributing to people contracted by your organization.  Furthermore saying it is "a way around test flight" is not accurate.  You could easily do what test flight is doing yourself with an adhoc certificate.